# Determinant of a matrix's second power equal to 1, so what will be its first power's value?

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If it is given that $B^2=0$. Then can I directly take the determinant on both sides and prove that determinant of $B=0$?

> Given:$B2=0$

> Taking determinant both sides

> $|B^2|=|B|^2$

> $|B|^2=|0|$

> $|B|=0$

This was correct.

[But I now have a doubt when $A^2=I$, why can't $A=I$ the same way we did for $B=0$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2bku.png)

If
$A^2=I$

$|A|^2=|I|$

$|A|=1$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: $|A|=\pm 1$. $|A|$ is not always positive.

Comment: What are the solutions of $x^2=1$ ?

Comment: $|A|=±1$ Is this the correct answer?

Comment: The determinant can of course also be negative, so $\det(A)=-1$ is possible as well (in fact for odd size of $A$ , $A=-I$ is a concrete solution with determinant $-1$). Hence $|A|=\pm 1$ is correct. For $0$, we have only one solution because $-0$ and $+0$ fall together.

Comment: Perhaps you considered $|A|$ to be something like the absolute value, which is why I would prefer the notation "det"

Comment: Can you please check the attached image? There it is said that, A is not I but $A^2$ is I. How is this possible

Comment: $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}^2=I$ for instance.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you so very much, now it made sense why $det A ≠ 1$ but still $det A^2= 1$